# MySQL Access Issues [Read Post]

Tags: mysql, networking, mysql-workbench, portforwarding

I setup my MySQL server on a server unit connected to PFSense router that is in turn setup on my home router that is DMZ mode for PFSense, PFSense is portfordwarded.

I can access MySQL from other hosts and from local host but if i try to access MySQL by using my public ip that both the server and my computer that needs to connect to my mysql database it won't allow the connection.

Localhost wont work for that as this is my connection settings

Modem/router Branches into 2 networks, My personal network the pc i am trying to connect to mysql from

And modem/router -> PFSense -> Server Unit with MySQL
modem/router -> Personal Computer - Trying to access Server unit MySQL through public ip address since localhost does not work.

Any help please!

Comment: This is a networking problem, not a programming problem. Try [sf].

Comment: Never once said it was programming problem??

Comment: You posted here, and SO is for answering programming questions.